# Is there a way to find a single occurence of a digit in a vector and ignore duplicates in R?

Tags: r, indexing, duplicates, find-occurrences

I have an array of numbers and I'd like to find the index of a specific digit ONLY when it's occuring alone, NOT when it's occuring in a sequence of the same digit.
For example:

```
a <- c(1,2,4,5,5,8,1,2,8,8,8,4,3)
```

I would like to find the index of the SINGLE 8 occuring at index 6, I'm not interested in any of the other digits, nor in the sequence of 8's occuring at index 9-11. 
Is there a clever way to do this in R?

Comment: `library(dplyr); which(a == 8 & lead(a, default = 0) !=8 & lag(a, default = 0) != 8)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be `rle`.  Apply the `rle` on the `vector`, create a logical index based on the `values` and `lengths`, and then wrap with `which` on the `rep`licated logical `vector`

```
which(with(rle(a), rep(values == 8 & lengths == 1, lengths)))
#[1] 6
```